# Flipping a array of strings horizontally

Tags: arrays, sorting, mirror

what I mean by is in a text file how would I flip the wording Adam, Sandler to Sandler, Adam

the code I have so far:

```
namespace Hw4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private static List<string> names;
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {   
            names= new List<string>();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("NameInput.txt");

            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                names.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }

            char[] split={','};

            names.Sort();

            string[] readArray = names.ToArray();

            foreach(String b in readArray)
                Console.WriteLine(" " + b );
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the programming language you are using is C#, if you want to flip the string, change your `foreach` loop to be like this `for` loop:

```
for(int i = readArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    String b = readArray[i];
    Console.WriteLine(" " + b );
}
```

Here what I do is starting to iterate at the end of the array, at position readArray.Length - 1 or last position and finish at the beginning or first position (0) of the array.